# How to test a single GET request in parallel for specified count?

Tags: python, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, playwright

I want to parallely send a GET request for the specified count say 100 times. How to achieve this using JMeter or Python ?

I tried bzm parallel executor but that doesn't workout.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
import threading

totalRequests = 0
numberOfThreads = 10
threads = [0] * numberOfThreads


def worker(thread):
    r = requests.get("url")
    threads[thread] = 0  # free thread


while totalRequests < 100:
    for thread in range(numberOfThreads):
        if threads[thread] == 0:
            threads[thread] = 1  # occupy thread
            t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(thread,))
            t.start()
            totalRequests += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter:

1. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and configure it like:

   [image]
2. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as a child of the Thread Group and specify protocol, host, port, path and parameters:

   [image]

   if you're not certain regarding properly configuring the HTTP Request sampler - you can just record the request using your browser and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)

For Python the correct would be using [Locust](https://locust.io/) framework as I believe you're interested in metrics like response times, latencies and so on. The official website is down at the moment

[image]

so in the meantime you can check https://readthedocs.org/projects/locust/

Comment: Thanks. Will this send the request in parallel ?